# NSString decoding non-standard percent

Tags: objective-c, ios

i am developing an iOS application, i have a `UIWebView` witch calls `JavaScript` function witch return to me a text encoded, to decode this text i am using the `NSString` method `stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding` but the problem with this method is i can not decode spécial caractérs like this : `%u2019`. How i can decode those caracteres ? (%uxxxx) thanks for your answers

Answer (score 0):

That looks like UTF8 encoding, not percent encoding. It's one of the Unicode encodings. I might be wrong about which one. but I think it's UTF8.

You should decode that using a method like stringWithUTF8String (if the data is already an NSString) or initWithData:encoding: (if the data from the JavaScript is NSData)

Comment: but when i use stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding it return a null value to me

Answer (score 0):

First thanks for every busy who answered to my question, but i have chosen this solution :

a non-standard encoding for Unicode characters: `%uxxxx`, where `xxxx` is a Unicode value represented as four hexadecimal digits. This behavior is not specified by any `RFC` and has been rejected by the `W3C`. The third edition of `ECMA-262` still includes an `escape(string)` function that uses this syntax, but also an `encodeURI(uri)` function that converts to `UTF-8` and percent-encodes each octet.

I have changed the `JavaScript` function witch uses the `escape()` function to encode the strings with the method `encodeURIComponent(uri)`; and in the Objective C code i use the standard function to decode my string `- (NSString *)stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:(NSStringEncoding)encoding`